# using word object in windows server

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, windows-server-2008

I have asp.net app which at some point takes word document, edits some of the data there and sends it to email.
While this is running good on my local computer where I have microsoft word, when I am trying to do the same thing from windows server without microsoft word installed, the document doesn't get created, and it seems that nothing is happening. 
Does anyone can tell me what do I need to install for this to work, do I need to install normal microsoft word application or I can install some assemblies?
Thanks, Laziale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3rd party tools that do this, you should NOT do it with MS Word directly.

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757